# How to extract an word and all his dependencies

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, data-science, sentiment-analysis

I'm not data-scientist but I'm on a project where i need to do aspect based sentiments analysis, I've already done an classifier for sentiment analysis but now, I need to do the "aspect based" part.

I have a list of aspects (4) and I need to find this aspect in a text, get all his depencies and analyse the sentiment of this group of words.

> The cake had good taste but the tea wasn't good at all

"The cake had good taste" = POS / "the tea wasn't good at all" = NEG

I've already explore stanford CoreNLP depencies parser but in french (because i've to do this in french) it's not so good (maybe I need to only keep Nouns and Adjectives for the parsing).

If you've any suggestions...

Comment: You are not going to find off-the-shelf packages that will outperform CoreNLP significantly- dependency parsing in a tough problem. I would suggest looking for a different algorithm that does not require accurate preprocessing. I am aware of one paper that uses convnets and minimal preprocessing, and the results are decent: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07043.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a French dependency parser as an alternative to the Stanford parser, you could use [Talismane](https://github.com/joliciel-informatique/talismane) or [BONSAI](http://alpage.inria.fr/statgram/frdep/fr_stat_dep_parsing.html). From memory, they both output similar ("flat") dependency structures as opposed to Stanford dependencies. Remember to check the licensing information wrt use on your project - Talismane looks like it is available for commercial use, but BONSAI probably isn't.